# How to parse JSON array using typesafe config?

Tags: java, json, parsing, config, typesafe

I've been trying to use typesafe config to parse array-structured JSON response from a web service and got an exception that config has type LIST rather than object at a file root:

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: Reader: 1:  has type LIST rather than object at file root
at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.forceParsedToObject(Parseable.java:136)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parseable.parse(Parseable.java:299)
at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseReader(ConfigFactory.java:622)
at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseReader(ConfigFactory.java:636)
```

```

It's really hard to believe that typesafe config unable to parse JSON of such structure, so I am assuming I am doing something wrong, thus need your advice how to approach this problem...

Context - writing a javaagent and need

- dot notation support and
- minimum set of dependencies - agent is using configs written in HOCON already, so unless it's really impossible to do with typesafe config, I'd rather not use another json parser

Options I was thinking of are:

a) to read entire response into memory (bad due to potentially long strings/byte arrays) and prefix it by some `fakeRoot` element, then parse it OR

b) to mess up with `ConfigDocumentParser` to extract list of nodes between `[` and `]` braket nodes then construct `Config` out of those somehow

Both (a) and (b) look way too hacky for the purpose (besides being inefficient) to me, so I wonder is it really a limitation of Config parser?

Here's the test code which might help to explain what I want in the very end:

```
@Test
public void config_howCouldItParseArray() {
  String webServiceResponse = "[{'element':'value'}]".replace("'","\"");
  // goal is to read data in streaming fashion from the response entity stream
  // StringReader is for illustration only
  Reader responseInputStreamReader = new StringReader(webServiceResponse);
  Config config = ConfigFactory.parseReader(responseInputStreamReader);
  Assert.assertEquals(config.getConfigList(".").size(),1);
}
```

I'd appreciate any advice or option to go with,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could write that string to json first which would wrap it into an object and then read back that new Json

Apologies I misread your question and I have since tried to resolve your problem without success. I have the following which works on serialisation but not deserialisation. Maybe it will help you further.

```
@Test
public void NoRootTest() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    TestClass[] test1 = new TestClass[1];
    test1[0] = new TestClass();
    test1[0].setElement("value");
    String string = mapper.writeValueAsString(test1);

    TestClass[] testClasses = mapper.readValue(string, TestClass[].class);
}

public class TestClass {

    private String element;

    public TestClass() {
    }

    public String getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(final String element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do it - this json array comes as a response from the service beyond my control, and, if I understand your suggestion right, I'd have to read the whole response into memory, prefix it with a fakeroot and then parse. It is basically option (a) I've listed above, which has a drawback of excess memory usage (compared to reading data straight from a stream or the response). I wish I could afford it...